# Unable to connect Sequelize in my local system to cloudSQ. I get this error:

Tags: sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql

I'm unable to connect postgres cloudsql from sequelize in my local system. I get this error:

> DB connection FAILED ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/prj-theexperiencebox:us-central1:theexperiencebox-01/.s.PGSQL.5432

Comment: That error means there's no Unix socket at the path. Are you running the Cloud SQL Proxy? See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-proxy for some details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.